# How does facebook check instantly user has logged out from other tab?

Tags: facebook, session, session-cookies, facebook-login

I was playing with inspect element the other day and what I did was I opened facebook in two tabs and logged out from the other tab. As soon as I returned back to the logged in tab, it showed me Login modal. How did it check instantly as no service request was made to allow them to check if the user has logged out.

Same happens with manual cookie clearance from Application tab in the developers console and also if you deactivate your account from app, the website open on your laptop shows to login. How does that happen so instantly? Is that a Websocket?

Comment: I can't replicate it - if I log out on one tab, I have to perform an action before I get the Modal. Furthermore I can say that it is not caused by Websockets (although that was a good guess). Does it work the other way around? (If you log on to one tab, does it also log you on in the other tab?)

Comment: Oh! Just open developers console. And clear all the cookies. It does open the modal that way.